# Why is finding $M$ eigenvectors on smaller matrix valid?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, image-processing

I am following [this article](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf) on face recognition. In "calculating eigenfaces" section, the authors present a solution for the problem of calculating a very big matrix:

Let $A_{N^2\times M}$ be an $M$ sized dataset, where each column in an $N\times N$ image. Instead of calculating the $M$ large eigenvectors of the $N^2\times N^2$ co-variance matrix they calculate the $M$ eigenvectors of $L=A^TA$ matrix which is of size $M\times M$.

- Why is this a valid\good enough solution?
- What are the criteria for a largest vector? larger in which seance?

Comment: Questions like these are yet another reason why I prefer the SVD presentation of these results as opposed to the eigenvalue versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B^T$ are $m\times n$ matrices (so both products $AB$ and $BA$ exist) then their characteristic polynoms $p_{AB}(\lambda)$ and $p_{BA}(\lambda)$ are almost the same (look for the sketch of proof [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices)):
$$
p_{AB}(\lambda)=(-\lambda)^{m-n}p_{BA}(\lambda).
$$
Therefore, their non-zero eigenvalues are the same as well.

Also, for any eigenvector $x$ of matrix $AB$ corresponding to a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$  the vector $Bx$ becomes an eigenvector of $BA$ and corresponds to the same eigenvalue.
$$
(BA)(Bx)=B(AB)x=B(\lambda x)=\lambda(Bx).
$$

Comment: Could you add some more detail on how this leads to the OP's result?

Comment: @nbubis Ah, sorry, I've concentrated on eigenvalues and forgot to add a note on eigenvectors. Will do in a minute.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan How long are your minutes :D. If possible I would still like further clarification on the eigenvectors.

Comment: @Shinobii What do you need to be clarified?

Comment: Perhaps I missed the reasoning, but why is it sufficient to find the M x M eigenvectors? I understand the math, just having a hard time explaining it to others. I suppose my question is, why are there only M meaningful eigenvectors in the $N^2$ x $N^2$ matrix?

Comment: @Shinobii: The other eigenvalues are zero. Basically, since the matrix in question is symmetric, the orthogonal complement of the $M$ eigenvectors' span is the nullity of the matrix.